# Rails 3 asset routing issues in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline, rails-routing

I currently have my assets in the jquery.rest.js and jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js files in my app/assets directory, yet i keep getting the following errors in my production logs.

```
Started GET "/assets/jquery.rest-f1490ffc30dcefe21715ae360de2bead.js" for 24.141.74.123 at 2011-12-20 18:40:50 -0500
Served asset /jquery.rest-f1490ffc30dcefe21715ae360de2bead.js - 404 Not Found (3ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery.rest-f1490ffc30dcefe21715ae360de2bead.js"):


Started GET "/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min-707e06de7fe351e6e77e419988c20fd6.js" for 24.141.74.123 at 2011-12-20 18:40:50 -0500
Served asset /jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min-707e06de7fe351e6e77e419988c20fd6.js - 404 Not Found (3ms)

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min-707e06de7fe351e6e77e419988c20fd6.js"):
```

My app works in development, i dont know why the long string is appended at the end of of the name of javascript files ie `-707e06de7fe351e6e77e419988c20fd6` for `jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js` in production

Comment: How does your `environments/production.rb` looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is called a fingerprint. Rails adds these in production mode to allow the assets to be cached on the client-side to improve performance. This is covered in the Rails [asset pipeline guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

One of the by-products of adopting this strategy is that you must pre-compile your files for production. This is done via a special task built in to Rails, and is usually run by Capistrano during deployment (you need to set this up - details are in the guide).

Also, when you have js and css files that are not in a manifest (the default application.css and application.js) they don't get precompiled unless you add them into a config variable.

Can you edit your question to include how you link to the files and also let me know if you are using the manifests and if you are precompiling or not?

Comment: Oh I totally missed reading the asset pipeline guide. Thanks for the assistance, bundle exec rake assets:precompile as mentioned in the guide seems to have done it

Answer (score 0):

Same issue I have.

The comment under the selected answer did not for me, but the following works for me:

```
- vim config/application.rb

# Comment this to avoid `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min-1116bf6f7eb1469bb3c60f6af13199ac.js");`
#    config.assets.debug   = true
```

Thanks.